# Prepared insert on duplicate key mysql queries in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm converting a node script into a ruby one just to brush up on the language (I haven't had much reason to use it as of late) and want to use a MySQL insert on duplicate key update query thats been prepared in advanced. The query is prepared like this

```
$add_update = db.prepare('insert into `titles` (`title`,`image`,`sku`) value (?,?,?) on duplicate key update `title`=?,`image`=?')
```

but that execute, it's not pretty

```
$add_update.execute('Item','item.jpg','00012534','Item','item.jpg');
```

Naturally those question marks get a bit confusing (I've already been tripped up my in the execute only updating the initial image). I'v tried binding names in the query, and while MySQL is fine with that the gem i'm using, mysql2, but it's documentation makes it seem like it's possible I don't see any specifics on how to do it.

Ideally I could pass a hash containing the keys and values I want to use, but my google-fu has failed me (I'm probably just using the wrong terms as I can't imagine that it's not supported). Something like:

```
$add_update = db.prepare('insert into `titles` (`title`,`image`,`sku`) value (:title,:image,:sku) on duplicate key update `title`=:title,`image`=:image')
$add_update.execute({:title=>'Item',:image=>'image.jps',:sku'00012534'});
```

I'm not using rails and chose mysql2 simple because it was the first gem I found to interface with my existing mysql server. If there is another gem that supports what I'm looking for I have no problem changing, this project is really just to get some ruby practice in and brush off the cobwebs.

Comment: A) Don't use global variables, those prefixed with `$` in Ruby. B) Don't use `;` unless it's strictly necessary (e.g. one-liners). C) You can call with hash arguments and omit the `{ ... }` braces on calls, like `execute(title: '...', image: '...', sku: '...')` which is much simpler syntax.

Comment: A) I know it's a global variable B) habit of javascript and PHP, I remove them as I notice them C) while the call works fine it doesn't pass the variables into the prepared statement, leaving me with a bunch of unexpected null field in the database

Comment: Again, **don't use global variables**. This is a very bad habit to get into. You should also ditch the `;` as the "When in Rome" principle applies here. Ruby absolutely doesn't use them. PHP *must*. JavaScript depends on your philosophy. Keeping it consistent is important.

Comment: Another thing to note is you can `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title=VALUES(title), image=VALUES(image)` with no need to repeat the placeholders.

Comment: Only three fields will be populated by this, the rest will be NULL. Which fields do you need to populate as well?

Comment: I am aware global variables are bad, but I was more interested in getting this working then getting them working well, I was simple working on the rough version to see if my ideas would work, it's far from production code. And yes, again In know the ; are un-needed, I put them in as habit then remove them once I notice them, I didn't update the question because while yes they are bad they are not important in regards to the question.

Comment: It's not that 3 fields were populating and the rest were null, it's that the 3 fields that should be populated were null. While using VALUES(title) and the like will work I'd still much rather be able to use properly named variables as it'll make the code more readable and easier to understand later.

Comment: This might be a limitation on your driver where it doesn't bind the same value multiple times. That's why using `VALUES(x)` instead of `:x` might help.